# Data is not being inserted into SQL Server Database hosted on Azure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Server database which is hosted on Azure. I am trying to input data into a table using C# and for some reason that data is not appearing in the table. Here is the code I am using. I don't know if the problem is in the connection string or something else.  Any ideas?

```
   //string connection = ("user id=MyGoals;" + "Password=pass;" + "Server=tcp:vclr5u6rk6.database.windows.net;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "Database=myGoals;" + "connection timeout=30");
            string connection = "Server=tcp:vclr5u6rk6.database.windows.net, 1433; Database=myGoals;Uid=MyGoals;Pwd=pass;";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
            conn.OpenAsync();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Users(FirstName, SecondName, Password, Email, DOB) values (@fn, @sn, @pass, @email, @dob)";
            string firstname = Page.Request.Form["firstname"].ToString();
            string secondname = Page.Request.Form["secondname"].ToString();
            string email = Page.Request.Form["email"].ToString();
            string password = Page.Request.Form["password"].ToString();
            string birthday = Page.Request.Form["birthday"].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", firstname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", secondname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", birthday);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Is there just no insert happening? Is it throwing errors? I don't understand what the issue is here.

Comment: its not throwing any errors its just not inserting it to the DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the `await` operator on your `*Async()` calls, so the code is executing incorrectly as it is not waiting for the operations (e.g. opening the connection) to complete.  Either make the method `async` and use the `await` operator, or don't use the `*Async()` methods as they are returning a task for the actions to be done *at some point later* that you aren't waiting on to complete.

For example:

```
 public async Task Foo()
 {
     /// <snip />

     await conn.OpenAsync();

     /// <snip />

     await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

     /// <snip />
 }
```

or:

```
 public void Foo()
 {
     /// <snip />

     conn.Open();

     /// <snip />

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     /// <snip />
 }
```